# Precision in a logarithmic function with Python

Tags: python, precision

I am trying to plot the logarithmic function: `x*log(1+1/x)` for very large values of x. I have checked for few terms since the overall plot was not good and the problem seems to be that although this function should never be higher than 1, for some points it becomes larger than 1. I believe it has something to do with accuracy of the log function.

for the following values of x:

```
[ 5.4380181e+11  3.1688845e+12  4.5195668e+13  7.4634268e+14  1.2442192e+16
  2.0754228e+17  3.4624427e+18  5.787843e+19  9.9925409e+20  2.6069079e+22]
```

I get for `x*np.log(1+1/x)`:

```
[ 0.99999999  0.99999989  0.99999774  0.9999925  0.99959801  0.99007829
  1.1261964  0.0  0.0  0.0]
```

As you can see the 7th term is bigger than 1.

I have tried using `log1p` instead but that gives non-sensical answers.

I have also tried using `np.float128()` but I get exactly the same results as above.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried with `log1p`? It should be able to give the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual page for `log1p`. It does *not* take the same argument as `log`. I guess that explains the "non-sensical answers".

It works for me:

```
l = [5.4380181e+11, 3.1688845e+12, 4.5195668e+13, 7.4634268e+14, 1.2442192e+16, 2.0754228e+17, 3.4624427e+18, 5.787843e+19, 9.9925409e+20, 2.6069079e+22]

[n*log1p(1/n) for n in l]
```

Output:

> [0.9999999999990805,
>   0.9999999999998422,
>   0.9999999999999888,
>   0.9999999999999992,
>   1.0,
>   1.0,
>   1.0,
>   1.0,
>   1.0,
>   1.0]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Yes that seems to work now, I feel so stupid. However, I get all 1.0, even using np.float128. Do you know why?

Comment: @Andrés Glad to help. No need to feel stupid; all programmers do these kinds of mistakes from time to time. Numpy defaults to 8 digit of precision for floating point output, so what you see is not whats actually there :) The numbers are rounded up to 1.0. Try changing Numpy's default with `np.set_printoptions (precision=20)` or print them an other way.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!